# Matrix multiplication property

Tags: matrices

### Help me please!

So consider  two matrices of integer numbers:
$$ A_{m,n}, B_{n,k}  $$
I want to find product of them
$$ C_{m,k} = A_{m,n} B_{n,k} $$
Let
$M$ is a very large number.
$$ D = (10^0,10^M,10^{2M},..,10^{(k-1)M}) $$

$D_j$ – $j$-th element of $D$. 
 $B_j$ – $j$-th row of $B$.
 $A_i$ – $i$-th row of $A$. 
 $C'_i$ - $i$-th element of vector $C'$, so that:

$$C'_i = A_i⋅ ((B_1⋅D),..,(B_n⋅D)) ,∀ i = 1..m$$
Then
$$c_{i,j}={C'_i/D_j} \mod D_{2} , ∀ i = 1..m,j = 1..k, c_{i,j} \in C$$
So I need a $2n^2$ multiplication (or not ?) for calculate a matrix product via precalculation $D$ and $(D ⋅ B_j)$ for all $j = 1..n$.

- First question: Is it really $O(n^2)$ multiplication for calculate
  matrix product, or not ?
- Second question: Are there other possible ways to multiplication
  matrix with this idea? (for example another operations )

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication

Answer (score 1):

There is no known $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ general algorithm for matrix multiplication, although it is believed that one may exist.

The closest one can get is a (recent) slight improvement over the Coopersmith-Winograd algorithm.

Regarding your second question, there may be other techniques to come up with a matrix product, but almost certainly they include addition and multiplication. There is no obvious "natural" operation, but the rules of algebra certainly allow us to create our own. Nevertheless, working in the group of integers, there are only so many operations that we can concoct without resorting back to addition and multiplication.

Comment: You mean $\mathcal{O}(n^{2+\epsilon})$?